# Libcurl doest write cookie correctly in cookie.txt

Tags: curl, cookies, command-prompt, libcurl

I am setting up an API link between two pieces of software. In the process I need to call APIs with java.
(please consider me as a newbie).

Before implementing the API calls in the Java code, I wanted to get reliable server responses in the console by formulating valid cURL calls. I am facing the following problem :

I authenticate to the server, which return a cookie file that I store in a cookie.txt file for future interactions. However, cookie.txt does not contain any session information. Here is its content :

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# curl
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.
```

When trying on a different computer the same cURL request it works fine, and contains user and session infos. I concluded that it had to do with my version of cURL. However, both computer are running the same version (which I think is the latest) :

```sh
C:\Users\victor>curl --version
curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL
Release-Date: 2017-11-14, security patched: 2019-11-05
```

At this point I don't know anymore. Can you please help me what is wrong with my environment ?

Thanks,

Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I did not find a solution, but I have found a workaround.

First thing, I added a `--dump-header header.txt` option to my curl request. This will create a .txt file which contains all the details of the session to include in subsequent authenticated requests.

Next, using Java File and String manipulation, I processed the header.txt file, to extract the session info. I then parsed the session info as a String and re-run my curl request using the option `-b myCookieString`, instead of `-b myCookieFile.txt`

I know this sound like a hella complicated for a problem so insignificant, but I have pulled my hair for 2 full days to come up with this solution.

PS : To know about the format of `myCookieString`, have a look inside your header.txt file as the Set-Cookie lines.

**-- EDIT --**

The problem has stopped occurring on its own... The curls and cookies run without issues now. Strange... Nevertheless, the solution described above will always work (it has for me).